# bootstrap navbar toggle button is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming, togglebutton

I'm working on a responsive wordpress theme with Bootstrap v3.0.2.

In mobile/tablet browsers instead of the whole menu i need to show the Bootstrap toggle button. My button is showing, but when I click on it nothing is happening. This is code I wrote in my `header.php` :

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

And the one I wrote in `function.php` :

```
function wpt_register_js() {
    wp_register_script(
        'jquery.bootstrap.min', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 
        'jquery'
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap.min');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_register_js' );

function wpt_register_css() {
    wp_register_style(
        'bootstrap.min', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_css' );
```

the footer.php code contains:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <?php wp_footer();?>
   </body>
```

the header.php contains:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
   <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

   <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <?php wp_head(); ?> 

    </head>
```

**this question is resolved by using the answer of  Bass Jobsen**.thanks friend

Comment: given answer will fix your issue, if still exists, share url where it has issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar first. Your navbar requires javascript:

> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the
>   navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view
>   the content within the .navbar-collapse.

Make sure you include bootstrap.js in your document. You forgot to upload this maybe?

**update** based on new information in your question:

enqueue all your javascripts and css in functions.php and remove them from your header.php and footer.php

javascript:

```
function skematik_jquery_js(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

function wpt_register_js() {
    wp_register_script(
        'jquery.bootstrap.min', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 
        'jquery'
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap.min');
}

/* Load Scripts */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'skematik_jquery_js' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_js' );
```

css:

```
function wpt_register_css() {
    wp_register_style(
        'bootstrap.min', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_css' );
```

Comment: thank u for your response sir. i have used the above code for adding the javascript file bootstrap.min.js file. is that the file you mentioned? or did i missed any other js file?

Comment: yes, that's the file. I enqueue the scripts on `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of jquery mostly. I don't expect this cause your problem. You will also have to enqueue jquery. If possible show an url with the representation of your problem.

Comment: see the answer of @zessx or consider using https://github.com/bassjobsen/jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme

Comment: so as per his answer i should delete the enqueue code from functions.php. right sir?

Comment: nope try to remove the first one, it's in your theme header i think so. Also read http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/wordpress-development-properly-load-javascript-set-dependency/. enqueue jquery and boostrap and set the dependeny of jquery for bootstrap.

Comment: oh... the first one means the function wpt_register_js()? ? (i'm asking these many doubts because i'm so confused.sorry sir :( )

Answer (score 3):

you should :

1. Load jQuery and Bootstrap.js once, not twice each
2. Load jQuery **before** Bootstrap.js

Currently, you've got :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.drjulians.com/wp-content/themes/new_responsive/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.6"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.drjulians.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2"></script>
</body>
```

The console output confirm what we can guess :

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery

When you load Bootstrap.js, jQuery is still not loaded.

Comment: I had similar issues - load `jquery` before `bootsrap.js` the navbar `toggle` works now

Answer (score -2):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.drjulians.com/wp-content/themes/new_responsive/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.6"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.drjulians.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2"></script>
</body>
```

I've Added the above code to my HTML and it worked on IE just fine!! THANK YOU!!